# Ffmpeg cropping, changing resolution and FPS in one process

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg

I have a video that I need to crop, then change resolution and then change fps for my needs.

I have tried 3 different processes and it leaves me with a video that looks blocky and very much inferior to the original quality.

Is there a way to do the three processes in one?

Original file is 520x360 @ 25fps, required output would effectively crop to 480x360 centrally, resize to 256x192 and change fps to 14fps.

And help would be appreciated.

I realise that if I used a lossless format at each point in the 3 processes, then I would not lose quality, but I do not know which format will be lossless.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/advice/0/how-do-lossy-lossless-video-formats-affect-your-editing

Comment: `ffmpeg -i input -vf fps=14,crop=480:360:20:0,scale=256:-1 output`

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for that.